# Recommendations for Knowledge Base and Chat Bot application with API

Tags: api, knowledge-base

I'd like to organise our organisation's "knowledge base" base. It's currently spread across a number of Google docs, old Word docs, Trello cards, website articles, etc.

I'd like for it to live in one place that's well organised.

I'd also like to be able to train a chatbot on that data, so that our team can interact with the knowledge-base. The chatbot would ideally be just an API-based solution so I can plug it into Google Chat or Slack.

Broadly, the knowledge is either:

- Things only our team need to know about
- Things both our customers and team need to know about So it would be great to be able to use tags, or similar, to organise the knowledge and be able to display it to customers too.

An API would be great so we can consume the content across multiple platforms.

We're a small team of 6 people so not seeking some sort of enterprise-based solution.